# How to plot month on x, value on y, separated by year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot all years-month on the x-axis and month value on the y-axis. Additionally, I would like to color the data points based on the year they belong to. I have used time-series data from a [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption?select=DOM_hourly.csv) to achieve this, but I am not getting the exact output that I intended.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
colors_list = list(mcolors.XKCD_COLORS.keys())

df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/hourly-energy-consumption/DOM_hourly.csv')
df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True, drop=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# drop duplicated index
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
## Monthly mean dataframe
mdf = df.resample(rule='M', kind='interval').mean()#.to_period('M').mean()
# Plot seaborn
mdf['Year'] = mdf.index.year
mdf['Month'] = mdf.index.month
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.scatterplot(x='Month', y=mdf.columns[0], data=mdf, hue='Year',ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Present output I got:

[image]

Desired output: Why I like below plot, not the previous one: Because, I can see the year-to-year pattern. Also, I can check if more then one month have same pattern.

[image]

To achieve my desired output, I need to run the following code:

```py
# Draw plot showing year to year change for the same month
years_list = mdf['Year'].unique()
years_color = colors_list[:len(years_list)]
## Append colors to the main df
mdf['year_color'] = mdf['Year'].map(dict(zip(years_list,years_color)))

for one_month in range(1,13,1):
    one_month_all_years_data = mdf[mdf['Month']==one_month]
    x_ticks = np.linspace(0,1,len(one_month_all_years_data)+1,endpoint=False)[1:len(one_month_all_years_data)+1]
    one_month_all_years_data['All years-months'] = None
    one_month_all_years_data.loc[:,'All years-months'] = x_ticks + one_month
    ax = sns.scatterplot(x='All years-months',y=mdf.columns[0],data=one_month_all_years_data,
                   hue = one_month_all_years_data.index, hue_order = one_month_all_years_data['year_color'])
    sns.move_legend(ax, one_month_all_years_data.index)

plt.show()
```

Output I got going towards the desired output:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_32/2084798528.py:74: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  one_month_all_years_data['All years-months'] = None
/tmp/ipykernel_32/2084798528.py:75: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
........
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more why the first plot is not what you want?

Comment: @jared I cannot see the trend from year to year. Also, I can not see if more than one month have similar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

- The customary method for showing year-to-year seasonality trends, is the plot each year as a separate line.
- [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with [`kind='line'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) calculates the mean, and adds a 95% confidence interval with the `errorbar` parameter, so it's not necessary to manually perform those steps.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from calendar import month_abbr  # for an ordered list of months

# load the data
df = pd.read_csv('AEP_hourly.csv')

# convert the column to datetime dtype
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)

# extract year
df['Year'] = df.Datetime.dt.year

# extract abbreviated month names
df['Month'] = df.Datetime.dt.strftime('%b')

# set the Month column to ordered categorical values so the x-axis will be ordered correctly
df.Month = pd.Categorical(df.Month, month_abbr[1:])

# plot
g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df, x='Month', y='AEP_MW', hue='Year', palette='tab20', marker='o', height=7, aspect=2, errorbar=None)
```

[image]

- Optionally, plot bars for each month.

```py
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='Month', y='AEP_MW', hue='Year', palette='tab20', height=7, aspect=2, errorbar=None)
```

[image]